# How to make user to decide whether to start SSO or just log in to SP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-saml

I am using spring saml for configuring sso. I have followed the spring docs for setting up sso, where user access the sp by logging in to Idp.

Now, I wan to give user a choice whether he wants to start a sso or not

If he selects the Idp then the authentication is done at the Idp and sso will be initiated

or

user may select just login which, then user will be authenticated at the sp side and allowed to access the resources.

Is there any way to do it? I am trying to modify the filters configured.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the sample application included within Spring SAML. It demonstrates the use case of having both IDP and form-based login in a single application.

Comment: I completed the requirement with the help of sample SAML application.
Thanks